# MySQL - copy field value of same record - Subselect

Tags: mysql

I would like to copy the value from one table cell to another in the same database record.

```
UPDATE article AS a
JOIN article AS aa
ON a.id = aa.id
SET 
  a.use_manual_date = 1,
  a.tstamp_manual = (SELECT tstamp FROM article WHERE id = a.id);
WHERE
  a.pid = 123
  AND a.use_manual_date = ''
```

After this, all records with id=123 and use_manual_date='' should have the value of "tstamp" in the field "tstamp_manual" of the same record.

Somehow I don't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt was a bit too complicated.

```
UPDATE article
SET 
    use_manual_date = 1,
    tstamp_manual = tstamp
WHERE
    pid = 123
AND use_manual_date = '';
```

should do it. There's no need for a join and a subselect.